# dereference of a reference

Tags: c++, reference, dereference

When writing this:

```
void foo(int*& x);
```

instead of `&` neutralizing the `*`, `foo` accepts `x` reference of a type `int*`, if I understand correctly.

but what happens when I write this:

```
void foo(int&* x);
```

is that a pointer to a reference?
will the compiler optimize it and take the actual value? since dereferencing a reference if the value it self.

EDIT:

so I can't take pointer to reference, but why is that? does it have to do with the address of the reference being a stack address?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if your compiler accepts it. Mine doesn't. Did you try it?

Comment: gcc: error: cannot declare pointer to ‘int&’

Comment: Reference to pointer is one of the most unreadable features of C++. What is this advantage over passing pointer to pointer?

Comment: `int*&` is a reference to a pointer. It is similar to `int**`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

§8.3.2 [dcl.ref]/p5:

> There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references,
>   and no pointers to references.

Answer (score 2):

`int&*` is not well-formed, no pointer to a reference can be taken.

Comment: @JohannGerell Try compiling declaration `void foo(int&*);`.

Comment: Sure - I commented on "no pointer to a reference can be taken" :) - sorry, should've been more clear.

Comment: @JohannGerell You are not taking a pointer to a reference, since after a reference has been declared it acts as an `l-value`. You are taking a pointer of an `l-value`.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin ITYM he is taking the address of an object